# Simple Youtube API Query and Save to Variable

Tags: php, search, youtube

I am trying to search youtube through the api and then save the search to a variable and then echo.  Having trouble getting this to work! I have included the entire code in html.  I'm not sure if it has to do with loading the youtube script library or more of a syntax error. Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$params="puppy";
function youtube_find_video($params)
{
    str_replace("'", "", $params);
    $q = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]/', '/', trim($params));
    $q = utf8_decode(utf8_encode($q));
    $replacements = array(',', '?', '!', '.');
    $q = str_replace($replacements, "", $q);
    $feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/{$q}?orderby=relevance&max-results=1";
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    if(!$sxml)
    {
        return false;
    }       
    else{
        $entry  = $sxml->entry;
        if(!$entry)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
        $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

        if($media)
        {
            // get video player URL
            $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
            $url = $attrs['url'];
            if(!$url)
            {
                return false;
                break;
            }
            parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
            $watch['id'] = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

            // get video name
            $watch['name'] = $media->group->title;

            // get <yt:duration> node for video length[minute]
            $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
            $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
            $watch['length'] = sprintf("%0.2f", $attrs['seconds']/60);

            $watch = simplexml_kurtul($watch); 
            return $watch;           
echo $watch;
}

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


} 
youtube_find_video();
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the exact errors you get? What's the weird behaviour? I would suggest you to use the Zend Gdata library, makes things like this a one-liner.

Comment: can you give an example of the one liner?  Sorry i'm kind of a noob.  Is there an easy way to query youtube and save data in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `youtube_find_video()` without the `$params`. Change the last line of PHP to:

```
youtube_find_video($params);
```

Also please give the errors you get. It's impossible to help without knowing what's wrong.